# How to show both validation error and holiday indication in table date cell?

Tags: visual-design

[image]

If a user inputs holiday date, he should see an indication for the same. Also, if date value is not passing the validation test - he should be seeing an indication.

Ex . If 2019/02/09 Sat is holiday and also, because of business logic, it has validation error. How can both indication be shown at the same time? or, what color indicate will be best for both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use the same indication for both cases.

You could use the icon for indicating a holiday (change icon not only color) and the background color for validation.

With the validation indication it is important to give the user an information why the date is not valid and with a hint what to do to get it right. This could be achieved with a popup or a small validation text (if it fits into the cell).

Comment: validation text can be below the field

Comment: @DesignerAnalyst as I understood it is a cell inside a table, so that would not be an option. If this is not the case I would definitely go with the validation text below the field.